# Why is there "Il" in "Il mio tesoro intanto"?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, articles

Why is there "Il" in "Il mio tesoro intanto"? Isn't "Il" just definite a article and thus not needed?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! For those who are wondering about where this sentence comes from, [context](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4htTs-s5pxc)

Comment: Why should it be “not needed”?

Comment: @DaG I assume because the rule in French and English works like that, and so someone unfamiliar with Italian might assume that's the case there too.

Comment: Thanks, @DenisNardin, a likely guess. OP, was that your thinking?

Answer (score 9):

Italian, unlike French, English or German, does not treat the possessive adjectives as determiners. They are ordinary adjectives and so are normally prefaced by the article when appropriate.

In particolar *mio* in *Il mio tesoro intanto* ("Meanwhile, my treasure") works exactly like *dolce* in *Il dolce tesoro intanto* ("Meanwhile, the sweet treasure").

Note that this allows one to use the indefinite article *un,uno* as well, which in English is impossible and requires the usage of periphrases to be expressed. For example

> Un mio amico (*A friend of mine*)

Comment: I realise I'm being fantastically thick, but what do you mean by "it's impossible in English to use the indefinite article"? "One friend of mine" seems legitimate, and could (in certain contexts) have the same meaning as "A friend of mine". What part of the puzzle am I not getting (I should add that my knowledge of Italian extends as far as 'gelato')

Comment: @Strawberry I mean that you cannot write "*\*A my friend*", so you need a periphrasis using the possessive pronoun "mine", or maybe something like "one of my friends".

Comment: Ah - got it! Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Strawberry No problem, and welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 6):

Italian *wants* the article with possessive adjectives and pronouns.

The article is omitted when the possessive refers to relations: *mia madre*, *mio padre*, *mio fratello*, *mia sorella*, *mia zia*, *mio cugino* and so on. With *madre* and *padre* the noun is always omitted, with other relations the name can be added: *mio fratello Asdrubale*. It is also omitted in vocatives: *Tesoro mio, ti amo*; it can also be *mio tesoro, ti amo*.

It is also omitted in special phrases: *casa mia* (that corresponds to the English *my home*), but *la mia casa* (which is *my house*).

Don Ottavio is singing

> Il mio tesoro intanto
>   andate a consolar.
>   E del bel ciglio il pianto
>   cercate di asciugar.

The article is used with *mio* and *bel*<sup>1</sup> (fused with the preposition *di*, as usual).

Among Romance languages, Italian is not unique for this: Catalan and Romanian use the article (postponed in the latter); French and Spanish don't. Related: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/26261/why-does-italian-use-definite-articles-before-possessive-adjectives-except-when

---

#### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> The adjectives *bello* and *quello* have peculiar forms:

1. *bel* and *quel* are used when before a name that takes the article *il*
2. *bello* and *quello* are used when before a name that takes the article *lo*
3. *bei* and *quei* are used when before a name that takes the article *i*
4. *begli* and *quegli* are used when before a name that takes the article *gli*

The forms are regular for the feminine (*bella*, *quella*, *belle*, *quelle*) and when the masculine adjective is postponed or *bello* is used as *aggettivo sostantivato*.

Comment: It makes sense to say The treasure. So in Italian one just add My to this. Thus we have My "the treasure". Am I correct or wrong?

Comment: @Hank I'd say rather "The my treasure", in the same way in which you say "The beautiful treasure" when the adjective is not a possessive.